# How to stop/exit/terminate dotnet core HostBuilder console application programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I'm trying to create a dotnet core console app. The app is a simply utility app and should start, do its thing and exit.
It's easy to achieve using standard console application template generated by Visual Studio.
But these days we have HostBuilder which seems to be more attractive because it brings unifying experience with WebHostBuilder, DI, Loggin, etc.

But it looks like this approach only designed for the long running background services. It will start and sit forever until the external termination event (like Ctrl-C).

Is there a way to end this type of application from the inside?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `IHostApplicationLifetime` to stop running of your application, you can access it from constructor and call `StopApplication()` method.

```
IHostApplicationLifetime _lifeTime;
public MyClass(IHostApplicationLifetime lifeTime)
{
    _lifeTime = lifeTime;
}
```

then StopApplication()

```
public void Exit()
{
    _lifeTime.StopApplication();
}
```

**Edited** to use `IHostApplicationLifetime` as `IApplicationLifetime` is deprected.

Comment: In case someone wonder where IApplicationLifetime will come from in this example you need to be using the DI for this. WIth HostBuilder you would have used ConfigureService to set things up for instance by registering an implementation of IHostedService with ServiceCollection.AddHostedService. Anything injected from that level going further will then be handled accordingly and framework stuff like IApplicationLifetime come out of the box so you do not have to manually add it to the container.

Comment: "This type is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative is Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime."

Comment: When I call _applicationLifetime.StopApplication() in console is written that "Application is shutting down..." but also execution of code continues and it fails on the Exception soon in the following code :(

Comment: @Gondil same problem here, you found any solution?

Comment: @liqSTAR unfortunately I don't remember anymore how I solved it or if I even solved it.

Comment: @Gondil gladly found out myself. I just returned right after the exit to avoid any ongoing commands.

Answer (score 10):

Even though you are using the [HostBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to register all dependencies in your application, you don't have to use the [IHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihost?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to execute a cmd line app. You can just execute your app via creating a service scope like so:

```
var hostbuilder = new HostBuilder();
builder.ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices); //Configure all services for your application here
var host = hostbuilder.Build();

using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
   var myAppService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyAppServiceToRun>(); //Use IHost DI container to obtain instance of service to run & resolve all dependencies

   await myAppService.StartAsync(); // Execute your task here
}

using (host)
    host.StopAsync();
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I needed to terminate my web service. So I used the approach like the solution marked answer, but the service didn't terminate instantly he continued with commands. So I needed to return right after the exit.

my killing method:

```
private void Exit(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime, ExitCode code)
{
    Environment.ExitCode = (int)code; //just shows in debug
    lifetime.StopApplication();
    // add log if you want to see the exitCode
}
```

the Configure method inside the Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    // code
    bool hasPendingMigrations = HasDatabasePendingMigrations(app);
    if (hasPendingMigrations)
    {
        Exit(lifetime, ExitCode.HasPendingMigrations);
        // we need to return explicit after exit
        return;
    }
    // code
}
```

You need to return.
The ExitCode is a custom created enum.

Edit:
After some time I moved the seeding into the Program.cs of my project which allows me to add test data / seed the database before even starting the server.

Answer (score 2):

The following works as of .NET Core 5.x/6.x

I needed the ability to shut down a service running on my web host.
They don't provide the granular ability to choose a specific web service that is running & I was having to continually shut down my entire site.  I wanted to be able to call a WebAPI method in my service & shut it down just the one service instead of having to stop IIS & restart.

Here's how you can add the ability to shutdown your service from your `HomeController` (or any other controller in your project).

In your `HomeController` add the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
      private IHostApplicationLifetime _lifeTime; // add private member
      // add appLifetime parameter to constructor 
      public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _lifeTime = appLifetime;  // init the private member var
    }
```

Now, we can add a method that you can access via JavaScript [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for example.

Further down in the `HomeController` add the following method.

```
[HttpGet("StopService")]
    public ActionResult StopService(){
        _lifeTime.StopApplication();
        return new JsonResult(new {result="true",message="<YourServiceName> is shutting down."});
    }
```

Now you can make a call to your service (even from the browser console window) like the following:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5243/StopService")
   .then(result => result.json())
   .then(data => console.log(data));
```

When that call completes you will see something like the following in your console.

[image: json results]

If you want to protect the method (I suggest you do) from outsiders then you can simply add a pwd as a parameter to the StopService method & take a hashed pwd to insure the user who is calling it is allowed.  I'll let you work out those details.

Answer (score 0):

1- Use the `UseConsoleLifetime()` while building the host in `Program.cs`

***Program.cs:***

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseConsoleLifetime(opts => opts.SuppressStatusMessages = true);
```

---

2- Registered `ApplicationStopped` event. So that you can brute force terminate the app by calling `Kill()` method of the current process.

***Startup.cs:***

```
public void Configure(IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime) {
 appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => {
  Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to shut down.");
 });

 appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => {
  Console.WriteLine("Terminating application...");
  System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
 });
}
```

Comment: What about using the `IApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()` as mentioned above? What does UseConsoleLifetime do for you? Should you use both?