# Net6 Console app, custom ConfigurationProvider question

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0, configurationmanager

I have a .Net6 Console application where I need to retrieve an array of objects from AppSettings.json.  Currently I am using an 'options' class to retrieve the array.

```
class ConfigOpts { class subOpts { /* property accessors */ }, public List<subOpts> SubOpts {get;set;}}
```

and

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(...).AddJsonFile(..);
IConfiguration config = build.build();
ConfigOpts opts = new ConfigOpts();
config.GetSection("ConfigOpts").Bind(opts);
```

Gives me an opts objects containing a list of subOpts.

One of the sub opt fields needs to be decrypted and encrypted at load/save time.  So I would like to use  a CustomConfigProvider and do the decrypt in the Load() method, and encrypt in a CreateSave() method.

I have amended my code to add a new class *ConfigOptsProvider:ConfigurationProvider,IConfigurationSource* and created an extension method AddConfigOptsProvider which is called on the binder above.

This works and I can hit the load() function in the config provider.

My two questions are:-

In the Load Method, how do I read the AppSettings.json file (I've looked for documentation but found examples for reading databases and other files but none for AppSettings.json).

Also, how do I call the CreateSave() function later?

Regards.

**Update**
I noticed as I have the ConfigOpts class that allows me to access the settings in a typed manner, it might be useful to try and use it.

In the load I have tried adding the following to the Load() method.

```
((IConfiguration)this).GetSection("ConfigOpts").Bind(_configOptions);
```

This code  is what I originally used (in the first example above). Unfortunately one cant cast to IConfiguration.

It would be great if this is all I need to do.

Comment: First of all will your createsave write back to appsettings.json?

Comment: that is the intention

Comment: As an addition if it is useful to a solution.  I have added the builder as a parameter to the ConfigOptsProvider and stored as an internal variable. It gives the load() function access to the underlying fileProvider.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72773955/9247039

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I'll look at it as an option - it would be great if I did not need to desterilize the whole appsettings though.   I have updated my original post to show my current thinking.

Comment: @CodingMytra - if you can post a basic answer I can mark it as such.  I've posted my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the System.Text.Json.Nodes namespace to read the appsettings files as JSON and them process.

I ended up with this routine in my Load() method which populated an internal custom data class with the required data, I can then access using a Get method.  Because of the number of fields in the  data Class, it meant I cannot use the provided Data property to return the result.

```
var fp = _fileProvider.GetFileInfo("appsettings.json")
using (Stream s = fp.CreateReadStream())
{
    var co = JsonDocument.Parse(s)?.Deserialize<Dictionary<String,Object>>?.Where(str => str.Key == "ConfigOpt").FirstOrDefault();

    var subObts = JSonNode.Parse(co.GetValueOrDefault().Value.ToString())["SUbOpts"];
    foreach(JsonNOde opt in subOpts.AsArray())
    {
         var optName = opt["name"]?.AsValue; 
    }

}
```

I have removed most of the null checks and the filesystem watcher and also there isn't a check for different environments (appsettings files).  The structure is ConfigOpt:SubOpts:opt:property  where SubOpts is an array of opts.